# How to plotted graph save as a JPEG image in C#

Tags: c#, csv, jpeg, mschart

I want to save  my plotted graph as a JPEG image by clicking save button.Please give me to help for solving this.this is my plotted grapg look like.[image: my plotted graph area]

This is code that I used to plotted the graph.

```
 private void Output_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<Graph> ObservingData = new List<Graph>(); // List to store all available Graph objects from the CSV

            // Loops through each lines in the CSV
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathToCsv).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
            {
                // here line stands for each line in the csv file

                string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');

                // creating an object of type Graph based on the each csv line

                Graph Inst1 = new Graph();


                Inst1.AvI = double.Parse(InCsvLine[1]);
                Inst1.AvE = double.Parse(InCsvLine[2]);

                chart1.Series["Speed"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                chart1.Series["Speed"].Points.AddXY(Inst1.Date.AvI, Inst1.AvE);
                chart1.Series["Speed"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;

            }
        }
```

This is my part of .csv file data as follows;

```
Name,AvI,AvE,Test
Amal,3.28000,100,TRUE
Kamal,3.30000,150,FALSE
Ann,3.32000,200,FALSE
Jery,3.34000,220,FALSE
TaW,3.39000,130,FALSE
Nane,3.40000,125,TRUE
Petter,3.42000,300,TRUE
Sam,3.46000,265,TRUE
Daniyel,3.50000,245,TRUE
Don,3.62000,146,FALSE
Zip,3.64000,201,FALSE
Sera,3.68000,300,FALSE
Perera,3.70000,200,TRUE
Dam,3.90000,170,TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example with using the `SaveFileDialog` and outputting the chart as a png image.

```
private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string path;
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Png Image (.png)|*.png";

        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = sfd.FileName;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                chart1.SaveImage(path, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using SaveImage method on chart control?

```
  public class Chart : Control, ISupportInitialize, IDisposable
  {

   /// <summary>Saves an image to the specified file.</summary>
   /// <param name="imageFileName">The name of the file in which image is saved to.</param>
   /// <param name="format">The image format.</param>
   public void SaveImage(string imageFileName, ImageFormat format)
```

Sample usage

```
speedChart.SaveImage("speedChart", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: I am a new beginner so I do not have any idea about how I want to start to save that jpeg image.I added my plotted graph code for this question.please give me help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this.This is working code for that.

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                this.chart1.SaveImage(dlg.FileName, ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
            MessageBox.Show("Chart details Successful saved as jpeg image");
        }
```